# Make apache only accessible via 127.0.0.1, is this possible?

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-7, httpd.conf, loopback

I've set up my Apache server, and the PHP/MySQL works well!

But the issue is, how do I keep this private, since it's a **development-only** server?
The only reason for keeping the content private is if a script went wrong, I don't want Apache errors showing up if it became a public-facing site (and the fact others share the same network too!), and I'm less likely to use my PC as a webhost - I'm more likely to go down using the webhosting provider route for an actual live site.

Currently I can access it three ways:

- http://localhost (or http://127.0.0.1, the alternate way and localhost's IP but either way is acceptable with me!)
- http 192.168.0.1 (my router's IP)
- http pc-name-here (name of my PC, obviously this varies between Windows PCs!)

[note, can't post links, so for the other two you'd have to insert the colon/forward slash as in the first one].

However, I only want to access it via the first one. It's listening on port 80 (and I don't want to change that). Is this not possible, or am I mistaken? I know a bit more about PHP/webdesign than the network side of things, so this is a first for me!

Basically, I want it to be only accessible via localhost on that machine, and not the external IP address, or 192.168.0.1 .

Would I need to edit httpd.conf and use deny on every testbed site, or is there any other solution?

Example:

```
<Directory /www/vhosts/localhost/>
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
    order allow,deny
    allow from 127.0.0.1
            deny from 192.168.0.1
            deny from my-pc-name
</Directory>
```

- that's an example but I'm not sure what's right or wrong here!

My operating system is Windows 7 Ultimate.

I did have a look round the 'net, but some of it seemed a bit technical for me.

What would you recommend?

Answer (score 41):

The easiest way to do this is through the `Listen` directive. By defaults, there's a line in our httpd.conf that reads:

```
Listen *:80
```

Meaning it will respond ro requests on port 80 on all of your computer's network addresses. Changing it to:

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:80
```

Will tell apache only to only respond to requests on the local adaptor, thus ignoring anything else.

Answer (score 15):

The listen option is probably best, but just as an FYI, you can do it using allow/deny like this

```
<Directory /www/vhosts/localhost/>
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>
```

`Order deny,allow` tells Apache to "Deny all requests unless specifically allowed" (`Order allow,deny` is the opposite, I.E. allow all requests unless specifically blocked)
`Deny from all` does a similar thing to `Order deny,allow` in that it'll block all requests from all IPs unless you specifically open them. It seems to be general practice to use both `Order deny,allow` and `Deny from all` but I'm not 100% sure why when they both do the same thing
`Allow from 127.0.0.1` says "Allow all requests from 127.0.0.1". 127.0.0.1 will map to localhost so you can use http://127.0.0.1/ or http://localhost/ and it'll be allowed

That will serve a 403 (Forbidden) error to anyone who requests the site no on localhost

Some other useful stuff;
`Allow from 192.168.0.` will allow request from anyone on your network (Providing your network is 192.168.0.0-192.168.0.255)
Allow/deny rules are processed in order, so

```
Deny from 192.168.0.2
Allow from 192.168.0.2
```

would allow requests and

```
Allow from 192.168.0.2
Deny from 192.168.0.2
```

would deny requests from 192.168.0.2

So

```
Deny from 192.168.0.2
Allow from all
```

Would allow requests from 192.168.0.2, even though it had specifically been denied.

You can also use Allow/Deny rules in .htaccess files or on a per-directory basis

Comment: Besure it's "Order deny,allow", not "Order allow,deny". A frequent tiny mistake people constantly make.

Comment: I found that `http://127.0.0.1/` and `http://localhost/` behave differently. `allow from 127.0.0.1` will still deny accessing from `localhost`, unless I add `allow from ::1` (I figured it out after running `ping localhost` in a command line)

Answer (score 4):

I made changes to ports.conf in /etc/apache2 so that each reference to Listen to a port was only listening to localhost. No other files seem to have listen command in. After restarting apache these changes seemed to have desired effect.

/etc/apache2/ports.conf

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
########################## Listen 80
Listen 127.0.0.1:80

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
# If you add NameVirtualHost *:443 here, you will also have to change
# the VirtualHost statement in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl
# to <VirtualHost *:443>
# Server Name Indication for SSL named virtual hosts is currently not
# supported by MSIE on Windows XP.
###############################Listen 443
Listen 127.0.0.1:443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
##################################Listen 443
Listen 127.0.0.1:443
</IfModule>
```